# Python sqlite3. Writing to a table from pandas read_csv results in error: Incomplete input

Tags: sqlite, dataframe, sql-insert, python-3.8

*I'm running on Python 3.8 and have the following code:*

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('feedback.db')  
c = conn.cursor()

read_feedback = pd.read_csv (r'C:\jup\feedback.csv', parse_dates=['Created'])

read_feedback.to_sql('FEEDBACK_IN', conn, if_exists='append', index = False) # Insert the values from the csv file into the table 'FEEDBACK_IN' 

c.execute('''INSERT INTO FEEDBACK_IN (Feedback, Created, User)''')`
```

*The table has been created using this code:*

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE FEEDBACK_IN
             ([generated_id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,[Feedback] text, [Created] date, [User] text)''')
```

*The sample from the csv:*

Feedback,Created,User
Quick help. Thank you!,29/12/2020,mailaddress@domain.com

*The dataframe from csv looks ok:*

```
                                         Feedback    Created                   User
```

0                              Quick help. Thank you! 2020-12-29 mailaddress@domain.com

*When I reach **c.execute('''INSERT INTO FEEDBACK_IN (Feedback, Created, User)''')** I get get an error thrown:*

**----> 1 c.execute('''INSERT INTO FEEDBACK_IN (Feedback, Created, User)''')
OperationalError: incomplete input**

I have played with the date formats, sequence of fields, now lost.

Comment: At a quick glance: missing [VALUES clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) (and [missing values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)).

Comment: Thanks! @DinoCoderSaurus